# How can I render HTML in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, html, jupyter

When I browse my file system through a jupyter notebook server I can view and edit HTML and other text files in addition to ipynb files.  However I want to view the files as rendered HTML instead of viewing them as a editable HTML.

In other words, how can I make a jupyter notebook server serve static content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already does, under `/files`. For example, when https://tmp39.tmpnb.org/user/IgoeEDdRLpRG/edit/featured/pandas-cookbook/README.md is the URL for editing a file, https://tmp39.tmpnb.org/user/IgoeEDdRLpRG/files/featured/pandas-cookbook/README.md is that file served up as-is (the first two segments of this example file path are specific to tmpnb servers).